# Is it possible not to perform transform() on test data

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, data-preprocessing

We know that the best practice in data preprocessing (such as standardization, Normalization, ... etc) is that while we perform `fit_trasform()` on the training data, we apply `transform()` testing data so that the learned parameters from scaling the train data are applied on testing data. Similar to this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform (X_test)
```

The question is: Does it also make sense to perform `fit_transform()` on the training data but NOT `transform()` testing data at all so that we get to test the model performance on actual real-world data that are not transformed at all? In fact, I tested this case using `scikit-learn` library for [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) before posting this question but I get an error so I thought this may not be an acceptable case to do, hence we always need to `transform()` test data if we apply any preprocessing technique on training data.

Thank you

Comment: Why? What for? Could you give an example when would you like to do that?

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example of the error you recieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it also make sense to perform fit_transform() on the training data but NOT transform() testing data at all so that we get to test the model performance on actual real-world data that are not transformed at all?

No. You've scaled the training data, so you should scale the testing data using the same scales as the training data. If I train a model using kilometers but then I measure my testing data in centimeters, my model will be wildly incorrect because the two measurements are using incompatible scales. The correct thing to do is rescale my testing data to also use kilometers.

> I get an error so I thought this may not be an acceptable case to do,

It's impossible to comment on this without a reproducible example. Here's an example that might help: if my preprocessing on the training data is using PCA to project from 100 dimensions to 2 dimensions, then by not applying the transformation to my testing data, I'd be passing an object with 100 dimensions to a model that only expects to receive 2 dimensions. This should, and does, cause errors.

Comment: You are right. The error has nothing to do with that. It was a bug in my code. Thank you for your answer.